# Adobe Sign API Create Web Form issue : use exist template

Tags: ajax, api, pdf, adobe-sign

How to use the template in Adobe sign API POST /widgets API.

I can't get transientDocumentId of Template.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

```
$.ajax({
...

data: JSON.stringify({
    fileInfos: {
      libraryDocumentId: "{libraryDocumentId}" // instead transientDocumentId
    },
    ...
  })
})
```